# When to exchange access token with refresh token

Tags: android, ios, concurrency, oauth-2.0, network-programming

I understand the flow to use OAuth2 is:

after the short-lived access token expires (server returning 401), the client has to request a new one using the refresh token.

To implement it in an iOS (with AFNetworking) or Android (with Volley) app, I imagine the network manager has to be able to detect returned 401 error and then send request to the auth server.

The problem is with the concurrent usage of the network. Consider the scenario where the access has expired, the app sends 2 requests: req1 and after 100ms, req2. Drawn on a timeline, this looks like:

```
req1 --> 401 --> (refresh req) --> OK, new access and fresh tokens --> retry req1
  req2 --> 401 --> (refresh req) --> 403, wrong refresh token
```

The final result is req2 will fail and the app logs user out because of the 403 error.

So my questions are

is this implementation heading towards a right direction? Or it's wrong to refresh after receiving 401? Should I instead refresh the token when the user starts the app (at the cost of slowing down app launch)

How can I solve the concurrency issue?

Comment: Which library are you using in android for api calling??

Comment: @ChandrakantDvivedi I am using Volley

Comment: I am using okHttp, where interceptor is provided in which you can intercept in between request and response.

Comment: Volley can do it too, the problem is then how to exchange the token

Comment: You need to generate new token using refrestoken and have to update original request header and again need to request server with new accesstoken. In Interceptor

Comment: I understand but that's not my question. I'm having trouble with the concurrency.

Comment: @Siyu do you already have some token manager implementation that works for sequential requests but may fail on parallel request?

Comment: @JánHalaša yes exactly. It works if I send requests one by one

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an existing token manager, I would add some extra logic into it (in Java):

```
class TokenManager {

  private String accessToken;
  private CompletableFuture<String> accessTokenRefreshComletableFuture;

  public CompletableFuture<String> getAccessToken() {
    if (this.accessToken is expired) {
       // If refreshed accessToken is being requested
       CompletableFuture<String> runningRequestFuture = this.accessTokenRefreshComletableFuture;
       if (runningRequestFuture == null) {
          // For thread safety, this assignment should be synchronized (or made atomic)
          // with the previous reading
          this.accessTokenRefreshComletableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
          // Request a fresh access token.
          // When you get a new access token, set the this.accessTokenRefreshComletableFuture 
          // complete and remove its reference from the manager class.
       }
       return runningRequestFuture;
    }
    // Synchronous result
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(this.accessToken);
  }
}
```

The manager doesn't return an access token, but a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) (Promise in JavaScript - asynchronous result). If the access token needs to be refreshed, check first whether the `/token` endpoint request is already running. If it is, return it's `CompletableFuture`.

This way, you would always have either a valid access token or a single `CompletableFuture` waiting for a new access token.

Comment: So the idea is to check the token before sending any request?

Comment: Yes, I think it's good to check it before sending - it's faster and you avoid too many forbidden requests hitting the server. But if you get HTTP 403 from the resource server, you should try again with a refreshed access token.

Comment: Okay, but if I do get a 403, how do I do to avoid running into the scenario described in my post?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant HTTP 401 - then you get a refreshed access token. You should not get HTTP 403 - `req1` will require the token to be refreshed and wait till it returns and `req2` would detect just wait for the refreshed token. Then they would both use the same valid access token.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit stubborn on this but how can I detect that req1 is requesting a new token and block req2?

Comment: Req1 will ask `TokenManager` to get a fresh access token. `TokenManager` will return a `CompletableFuture`. When `req2` asks for a fresh access token, `TokenManager` will return the same `CompletableFuture`, because the request has not finished yet. So `req2` will not detect that the access token is already being refreshed, but it will be blocked (its thread) until the refreshed token is obtained.